# Nvidia-settings showing different GPU temperatures

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-settings

I have noticed that after switching from Nvidia blob 295.x to 304.x, nvidia-settings utility suddenly shows GPU temp like 20 degrees less when GPU is under load (playing a game). It was around 80°C, with newer driver and tool it's around 60°C.

Why is that and why is the difference so big? Which one is the right temperature?

Comment: is vsync on? it matters